# How to make Firebase Push Notification Increase Badge Count When Receive Notification In maui blazor?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, maui, maui-blazor

I'm developing a app using maui blazor. I want to implement Firebase console to push the remote notifications. I am getting the notifications but I need notifications badge view count over app icon. How can I achieve the badge view count using FCM.

`<PackageReference Include="Plugin.Firebase" Version="1.3.0" />`

I'm using the above nuget package.

To get the FCM notification badge view count on app icon.

Answer (score 0):

**For iOS**

According to the official documentation [ApplicationIconBadgeNumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/uikit.uiapplication.applicationiconbadgenumber?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12), On iOS8+ we need to register for user notifications to be able to set the application icon badge number:

```
//Register this in the Appdelegate
UIUserNotificationSettings settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(UIUserNotificationType.Badge, null);
UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
```

Then you can change the app's badge in the PCL with `CrossBadge.Current.SetBadge(number);

Moreover if you want to set the badge on the native iOS platform, you can try `UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = number;` directly.

**For Android**

Android O introduces notification badges:

https://developer.android.com/preview/features/notification-badges.html

They show the number of notifications with a long-press on the icon.

Comment: Thank you for your response,  @Jessie Zhang -MSFT. I am currently developing an app using MAUI Blazor with .NET 7.0. I'm wondering if the code CrossBadge.Current.SetBadge(number); will be supported on both iOS and Android platforms.

Comment: Sorry, the code I shared above is from nuget `Xam.Plugin.Badge`, but it has not been updated for a while. So, it is not recommended now. But you can refer to the source code of it.